# Webpack + Typescript is compiling external imports into require, causing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm using TypeScript 4.5.5 and Webpack 5.67.0. I can import internal modules just fine, but when I attempt to import a module from my `node_modules` directory (in this case, `howler`), it gets compiled into a `require()` statement and my browser doesn't understand it.

Example: on line 1 of my file, I have:

```js
import * as howler from 'howler';
```

Then when I compile my `client.js` (transpiled from source TS files, browser facing, and accessed by `index.html`) and open the browser console, the JS has errored at this line:

```js
/***/ "howler":
/*!*************************!*\
  !*** external "howler" ***!
  \*************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = require("howler"); // <--- Right here: "Can't find variable: require"

/***/ })
```

I have experimented with a number of different configurations but none of them seem to work. It's worth noting that `require()` statements in my `server.js` (transpiled from a single server.ts file, server-facing code run by express to serve my API and `/public` directory) work just fine.

This is my `tsconfig.json` in my project root (same level as `package.json`)

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "ES6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "ES6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "src/ts/**/*"
    ],
}
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        'server': './src/server.ts', 'public/client': './src/ts/index.ts',
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }, {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals(), "express", "howler"],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        clean: true,
    },
    plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({ patterns: [
                { from: 'src/html/index.html', to: 'public/index.html' },
                { from: 'src/html/index.css', to: 'public/index.css' },
            ] 
        })
    ]
};
```

Additional notes:

- I see  `external "howler" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]` during the `npx webpack` build process.
- I have installed `@types/node` and `@types/howler`
- This happens with any external modules used in the `ts` files that are transpiled into `client.js`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the best solution was to:

1. Split the webpack config into two configs, one for client, one for server
2. Remove `externals` from the client config. It stopped compiling it into a node dependency and I was all set.